# Color list from mysql

Tags: css, list, colors

```
  {if $categoryID == $categories_tree[i][0]}
    {$categories_tree[i][1]}
  {/if}
```

Hi there, I'm using open source code to make editable list - tree of different categories in it.

This part of code above is responsible for showing each position who are noded. How can I color '{$categories_tree[i][1]}' ? Tried font with color but didn't work. Code like < b> works fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a div, assigning a class to that div, and then modifying css for the class. Something like this:

```
{if $categoryID == $categories_tree[i][0]}
  <div class="node">{$categories_tree[i][1]}</div>
{/if}
```

CSS:

```
.node {
  color: red;
}
```